# Keyboard shortcut for code folding in Spyder

Tags: spyder, folding

Is there a way to get a keyboard shortcut for code folding in Spyder?
Spyder 4 provides code folding, but I would like to have a keyboard shortcut (like let's say CTRL+m) to fold/unfold a section.

Answer (score 6):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately there's no shortcut to do that in our current version (5.2.2).

Comment: That would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would also be nice to be able to collapse all code at a certain level of indent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I think that's not possible due to technical reasons

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba: I am assuming there is still no keyboard shortcuts for fold/unfold in version 5.1.5?

Comment: That's correct, I updated the answer to apply to our latest version. Unfortunately, we haven't had time to do it, sorry.